# Decomposition of a permutation into increasing subsequences

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, permutations

Given a permutation $P$, the goal is to decompose this permutation into $k$ increasing subsequences $L_1,L_2,\ldots,L_k$, such that every element in $P$ appears exactly once in some increasing subsequence and one cannot decompose $P$ into $k'<k$ increasing subsequences. $|L_1|\geq |L_2|\ldots \geq |L_k|$.

The value $k$ is known to be length of the longest decreasing subsequence in $P$.

There may be several decompositions of $P$, however a decomposition $L_1,\dots,L_k$ is said to be an *ideal decomposition* if for every $i\le k$ and every disjoint increasing subsequences $L'_1,\dots,L'_i$, we have $|L'_1|+\dots+|L'_i|\le|L_1|+\dots+|L_i|$.

**(Question a):- How much time is needed to find an ideal decomposition?**

Example :-
Say the permutation $P=[1,7,8,2,9,3,6,5,4]$.

Then

$L_1= 1,7,8,9$

$L_2=2,3,6$

$L_3=5$

$L_4=4$

$P$ cannot be decomposed into 3 or lesser increasing subsequences, because it contains the subsequence 9654 and no two of these integers can belong to the same increasing subsequence.

$L_1,L_2,L_3,L_4$ is an ideal decomposition of $P$, because

1. if we have to choose only one increasing subsequence from $P$, then its maximum length is $|L_1|=4$
2. if we have to choose only two increasing subsequences from $P$, then their maximum total length is $|L_1+L_2|=7$
   ...
   and so on.

$P$ also has another ideal decomposition which is as follows

$L_1= 1,2,3,6$

$L_2=7,8,9$

$L_3=5$

$L_4=4$

**Bonus question:- Can this ideal decomposition be maintained dynamically in $o(n)$ time under insertion of the following type.**

If $|P|=n$, then $n+1$ is inserted in $P$ (to get $P'$) possibly at any index and data structure would now reflect the new ideal decomposition of $P'$. Initially $P=1$.
For example if $P=[1,7,8,2,9,3,6,5,4]$, then $P'$ can be [1,7,$\textbf{10}$,8,2,9,3,6,5,4]

This question is closely related to Young's tableau and Greene's theorem. I believe that this might be a well studied problem. Just need some references. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't make any sense of the definition. What does $L_1\ge L_2\ge\dots$ mean? What does it mean "if we need to choose" - choose for what purpose? Why would we *need* to do that? What does it mean "choosing the list $L_1,\dots,L_i$ would maximize the sum $L_1+\dots+L_k$" - is the $L_1,\dots,L_i$ a different list from the "ideal one"? If so, why does $L_1+\dots+L_k$ end in $L_k$ rather than $L_i$? What properties the newly chosen list has to satisfy? And what does $L_1+\dots+L_k$ mean in the first place? I'm completely lost.

Comment: If this is a previously studied problem, please give a reference to a comprehensible definition.

Comment: @ Emil:- The related problem of LIS and Young's tableau have been quite well-studied. William Fulton wrote a textbook on Young's tableau which captures a lot of the topics mentioned above.

I have also explained the example and clarified the notation abuse. $L_1$ was referring to the increasing subsequence as well as its length. I have rectified that abuse.

"need to choose", because there is a correspondence between this type of definition for ideal decomposition and the structure of a Young's tableau constructed from a permutation $P$ using Schensted's insertion.

Comment: I tried to guess the intended definition of ideal decomposition from the example, and edited the post accordingly. Let me know if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications Prof Emil Jerabek, however Prof Peter Shor figured out that my question was wrong. However, I am grateful for your time.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be assuming that an ideal decomposition exists for all permutations. It does not.

Consider the permutation

6 2 4 8 10 1 3 7 9 5.

The maximum length increasing subsequence is 4. If you take
$L_1$ = 2 4 8 10,
$L_2$ = 1 3 7 9,
then you get $| L_1 + L_2| = 8.$

This is the only way of getting two increasing subsequences whose lengths add to $8$, because neither $6$ nor $5$ can be in an increasing subsequence of length 4.

You can also decompose the whole permutation into three increasing subsequences

$M_1$ = 6 8 10,
$M_2$ = 2 4 7 9,
$M_3$ = 1 3 5.

But it is impossible to add an increasing subsequence of length $2$ to the subsequences $L_1$ and $L_2$.

If ideal decompositions of permutations into increasing subsequences existed for all permutations, they would probably be well-studied. However, they don't.

You could ask for an algorithm to determine whether an ideal decomposition exists, and if it does, to find one. I don't know if you would be interested in such an algorithm, or whether this problem has been studied. In any case, this would probably be better posed in a new cstheory.SE question rather than editing this one.

Comment: Never been so happy to be wrong.
Thank you Professor Peter Shor.